# How to get Babel to compile using webpack-style 'modulesDirectories'?

Tags: mocha.js, webpack, babeljs

Following this gist here
https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/daafb1e3cb8ad740b346

I was able to set up a cool folder structure for a pretty complex app using Webpack's 'resolve.modulesDirectories' -  I can reference shared components via module-type imports :

```
import MyModule from 'modules/MyModule';
```

where the file is in

```
src/app/modules/Foo/modules/Bar/modules/Baz/component.jsx
```

and MyModule is in

```
src/app/shared/modules/MyModule
```

---

The trouble is, when I try to run tests

```
mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register $(find src/app -name *.test.jsx)
```

the Babel compiler throws saying it can't find anything in 'modules/MyModule'...

Is there an analog to Webpack's 'modulesDirectories' in the Babel compiler config ?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use Babel's `resolveModuleSource` option to essentially rewrite the import paths, but you'd need to use the programmatic API to do it. So instead of using Mocha's `--compilers` option, use `--require` to load a script that calls Babel's require hook and passes the `resolveModuleSource` option. If you're using Babel v6 use the `babel-register` package and it'd look something like:

```js
require("babel-register")({
  resolveModuleSource: function (source, filename) {
    return filename.replace(/^modules\/.+/, "/abs/path/to/src/app/shared/$0");
  },
});
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this when you have n  shared folders in various places?

Comment: @Moezalez I'm not really sure what situation you're describing. Can you sum it up in the space of a comment? If not, terhaps ask it as its own question with more detail.

Comment: check out the `shared` folders here: https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/daafb1e3cb8ad740b346

Comment: @Moezalez Thanks. I guess you could implement the searching up the directory tree yourself in `resolveModuleSource()`, though it'd have to be sync. You might be better off just bundling the tests with Webpack once relying so heavily on a Webpack feature. See for example https://gist.github.com/ryanflorence/daafb1e3cb8ad740b346#gistcomment-1376396. Or instead of `shared/` you could probably use `node_modules/` and rely on Node's module resolution. Note though that it's still up in the air how resolution of ES modules will really work natively in Node.

Comment: Or just add node-glob

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to compile your tests using webpack:
https://webpack.github.io/docs/testing.html